# Backward elimination technique in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, selection, forward

I am a student at statistics department and I have a thesis about the factors of daily life behaviors related to obesity.

I made a test to 200 people and asked 30 questions like, if they smoke or not & fast-food consumption etc...

My question is ; How can i find the significant variables in which are mostly related to obesity situation using backward elimination or forward selection technique in MATLAB.

I am new at MATLAB and don't have any idea about where to start. Could somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox, take a look at the functions `stepwisefit` and `sequentialfs`. Both carry out forms of forward and backward feature selection. `stepwisefit` does stepwise linear regression, whereas `sequentialfs` is for general purpose sequential feature selection applicable to many model types.

Comment: `stepwisefit ` does not seem to support *backwards* stepwise selection and `sequentialfs` seems like an overkill for such a "simple" task.

Comment: @epsilon You can make `stepwisefit` do backward selection by setting the `inmodel` parameter (i.e. the initial set of variables) to include all the variables, setting `penter` (the _p_ value required to add a variable to the model) to zero, and `premove` (the _p_ value required to remove a variable from the model) to some positive value. If you don't like `sequentialfs` that's fine - but it doesn't seem that hard to me, and it's useful to have a general-purpose method that can be applied to things other than regression.